# Date format in GeoServer WMS requests strange

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I got some date values in layer properties.

When i use GetFeatureInfo request to WMS, i got date on day back, for example in DB or in WFS requests or in layer preview it is '2015-04-10', but i got '2015-04-09Z' in my WMS request.

How can i fix or change this output on server side?

Geoserver + PostGis

Comment: You are probably east of England and issue was known in April https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/33757545/. I do not know if it has been fixed in recent GeoServer versions. Which version do you have?

Comment: Russia, geoserver 2.8.1

Comment: Same problem for me. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Start your Goserver with this Java option:

```
-Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true
```

It will tell Geotools to not modify date objects (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/factory/GeoTools.html#LOCAL_DATE_TIME_HANDLING).

You need to have at least version 15 of Geotools for this to work.